# IOS Safari and javascript: how to turn on/off onscroll/ontouchmove seamlessly (using one continuous gesture)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, scroll, safari

I am stuck with my customized scrolling behavior on IOS Safari. The implementation of the scrolling behavior is basically divided by the native onscroll handler and an own handler for ontouchmove that modifies the absolute position of a div element:

```
    function disableNativeScroll(element) {
       // customized scrolling
       element.ontouchmove = function customHandler(e) { 
           e = e || window.event;
           if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
           e.returnValue = false;

           // do something smart here ...
       }        
    }

    function enableNativeScroll(element) {
       // native scrolling until top offset is 0
       element.onscroll = function(e) {
           if (element.scrollTop === 0) {
              disableNativeScroll(element);
           }
           return true;
       }
    }
```

So for example, while scrolling in the native mode the function to disable it is called at a given offset and the custom handler is attached to the 'ontouchmove' event.

Inside the Browser (Firefox, Safari, Chrome) the switch works smoothly. Also on Android (Chrome) the scrolling using touch is not disrupted. With IOS Safari scrolling is discontinued at the "breakpoint" and is only continued if I am interrupting the touch gesture and then resume it.

Please checkout the demo! If the background is partly green then the native scrolling is disabled and alternative events (touchmove, mousewheel, wheel) are detected to move the content. While a complete red background indicates that the native onscroll handler takes over the scrolling behavior.

Demo: http://crishushu.bplaced.net/stackoverflow/32160289

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/o16zcbrk/9/

Answer (score 0):

HTML sample

```
<div id="elm" class="no-scroll">...</div>
```

CSS to disable scrolling

```
.no-scroll
{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

JS to manipulate scroll

```
$('#elm').prop('scrollTop', new_scroll_value);
$('#elm').prop('scrollLeft', new_scroll_value);
```

To restore scrolling, just remove "no-scroll" class